# How to integrate with Pub/Sub using Cloud Run on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm stuck on using cloud run on GKE with pub/sub integration, here's my attempt and where I'm stuck at:

0) Following https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#run_pubsub_server

1) I'm using  "free wildcard DNS test sites" for kube cluster default domain (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/default-domain), do we need our own custom domains for properly(best practice) using pub/sub with cloud run on gke?

2) Domain verification:  Here I'm having trouble figuring out how to upload HTML file to the wildcard domain (I don't have user name/password, not sure how to upload the file to the web server)

3) I tried skipping ahead to enable HTTPS on my cluster, but when using `certbot-auto` to obtain SSL/TLS certificates, it asks me to deploy a `DNS TXT record` under `_acme-challenge.default.IP.ip.io`, how do I access my DNS records to do this for the wild card url? (and for `xip.io` suggested in the docs it already hits the cert issue rate-limits for letsencrypt)

Overall I'm having trouble with the docs in terms of what is needed for cloud run on GKE and what is for cloud run only, hopefully I'm on the right path and not too far off, any insights would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> do we need our own custom domains for properly(best practice) using
>   pub/sub with cloud run on gke?

You mentioned best practices, so yes you need one. Otherwise, with the exception of HTTPS(SSL) you can use one of the free wildcard sites.

> Domain verification: Here I'm having trouble figuring out how to
>   upload HTML file to the wildcard domain (I don't have user
>   name/password, not sure how to upload the file to the web server)

If you do not have the login for your web server, change the verification type to DNS verification. However, this will require that you can make changes to your DNS server.

> how do I access my DNS records to do this for the wild card url?

You cannot for a wildcard url as they do not provide you with that level of access. To make changes to your DNS records will require you to have access to your own DNS server. You cannot issue an SSL certificate for a domain that you do not control. You can only issue SSL certificates for your own domains.

Suggestion:

Test with Cloud Run (not Cloud Run on GKE).

Comment: Thanks a lot John, we're trying to test with GKE because cloud run has some limitations, but base on your answer the docs for cloud run on gke would not really work unless we secure a domain first